# On the endofunctor $\Sigma^\infty\Omega^\infty$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

1. Consider the co-monad $M:=\Sigma^\infty \Omega^\infty$ on the category of spectra.
   It is clear that given a pointed space $X$,  $M\Sigma^\infty X=\Sigma^\infty E(X)$,where $E(X)$ is the free unital $E_\infty$-algebra on $X$.
   As $\Sigma^\infty$ commutes with colimit,  $M\Sigma^\infty X$  is equivalent to
   the free $E_\infty$-algebra on  the spectrum $\Sigma^\infty X$, that is,
   to: $$
   \lor_n (\wedge^n (\Sigma^\infty X)_{hS_n}).\tag{1}
   $$
   Is this right?
2. It looks like given an  arbitrary spectrum $A$, there is no equivalence between
   $\Sigma^\infty\Omega^\infty A$ and $
   \lor_n (\wedge^n (A)_{hS_n})
   $
   Is there any general condition for having such  an equivalence?

Comment: I think for (1) you should assume that $X$ is a pointed _connected_ space, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For connected spectra $A$, there is an equivalence
$$\Sigma^\infty \Omega^\infty A \simeq \bigvee_{n=1}^\infty A^{\wedge n}_{h\Sigma_n}$$
if and only if $A$ is a wedge summand of a suspension spectrum.

This is Theorem 1.2 in N. Kuhn's paper *Suspension Spectra and Homology Equivalences* (TAMS, 1983). Kuhn calls spectra that are wedge summands of suspension spectra *spacelike*.

I am guessing that if $A$ is not connected then such an equivalence can not exist. It is easy to see that there can not be an equivalence of ring spectra.